# Transcendental and implicit functions

Tags: implicit-function, transcendental-functions

**Def**. An implicit function is a function that is defined implicitly by an implicit equation, by associating one of the variables (the value) with the others (the arguments). For example, 
$$F(x,y)=0$$$$ e^x+x+y-\sin(y)=0$$
**Def**. A transcendental function is an analytic function that does not satisfy a polynomial equation, in contrast to an algebraic function. For example, $$e^x-y=0$$

Can we state that

1. **all** transcendental functions of more than one variable are implicit functions

and vice versa

2. **all** implicit functions are transcendental functions of more than one variable

**Note**. I understand that the 1. point is incorrect, but if throw out "**all**", under what conditions will the 1. point be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit and transcendental functions are rather different, as

1. Implicit function:
   is a relation of the form $R(x_1,...,x_n)=0$,
   where $R$ is a function of several variables (often a polynomial, but sometimes transcendental)

$\ \ \ \ x^2+y^2-1=0 \ \ \ \ $  implicit (polynomial)

$\ \ \ \ x^2+e^y-1=0 \ \ \ \ $  implicit (transcendental)

2. Transcendental function:
   is analytic function that has not polynomial structure, as an example:

$\ \ \ \ x^2+e^x-1=0 \ \ \ \ $   transcendental

$\ \ \ \ x^2+e^y-1=0 \ \ \ \ $  transcendental (implicit)